# How to edit the inferred language for a tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to add the inferred syntax highlighting language to a tag, and if so, how?

This came to mind when writing an [answer to a gulp-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31846306/145173). I had to specify the language manually, but JavaScript should have been inferred.

Comment: There is a related question on what to do [if a tag's language is broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251334/145173). This question is more general, including the case of no tag language at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done by a moderator.

I have now added the lang-js hint to the [gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp) tag.