# Next.js and Next.js 13 tags should select TypeScript highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Related: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300883/how-to-edit-the-inferred-language-for-a-tag), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371148/could-vue-js-questions-be-adjusted-to-highlight-correctly), probably many others, some out of date ([Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) is abandonware).

Is there an alias system for inferring the language which is moderator-editable? [An example here of where this is a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503099/trouble-configuring-error-page-for-next-auth-next-13). If a language tag isn't provided, the [`typescript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) tag would be appropriate for highlighting because plain JavaScript highlights fine in TypeScript. If this question needs to be opened as a bug report somewhere, no problem; just let me know.